# findbugs msg: Method call passes null for unconditionally dereferenced parameter

Tags: java, date, findbugs

I have below piece of code:

```
          if (null != result[1]) {
                mySearchTO.setDt(dateFormat2.parse(result[1].toString()));
            } else {
                mySearchTO.setDt(null);
            }
```

Where result is a object array and dateFormat2 is a SimpleDateFormat.

Findbugs is giving the following:

A possibly-null value is passed at a call site where all known target methods will unconditionally dereference it. This is very likely to result in a null pointer exception.

What does this message tell ? How to solve this error ?

I am checking the result for null so that my Parse method does not break. But if the result is null, I want to set the Dt field in SearchTO to some default which here I am taking as null.

Is there a better default option for date ?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Is the error in `dataFormat2.parse` or `mySearchTO.setDt`?

Comment: @Gabe: Its in mySearchTO.setDt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be complaining that `mySearchTO` or `result` could be null.

Comment: @Puce Depends on whether you believe the `all known target methods will unconditionally dereference it.`

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your `mySearchTO` field itself may be null?

Otherwise, it may not be realizing that `result[1]` is already being checked for null - possibly complicated by the fact that it's reading a value out of an array.  What if you do something like `Object o = result[1];` above the conditional, check for `o != null` as the conditional, and then call `o.toString()` within the conditional?

Answer (score 0):

The message refer to array `result`, you only check that element under index 1 is not null, but array itself could be also null.

```
 if (result != null && null != result[1]) {
    mySearchTO.setDt(dateFormat2.parse(result[1].toString()));
 } else {
    mySearchTO.setDt(null);
 }
```

I assumed that mySearchTO and dataForma2 are initialized correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Per my reading of [NP_NULL_PARAM_DEREF explanation](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#NP_NULL_PARAM_DEREF), Findbugs is trying to warn you that this statement will bite you with NPE:

```
            mySearchTO.setDt(null);
            // guess there's line at mySearchTO.setDt looking like...
            // ... valuePassedToDt.toString() - would give NPE for null
```

> ...This method call passes a null value for a nonnull method parameter. Either the parameter is annotated as a parameter that should always be nonnull, or analysis has shown that it will always be dereferenced...

To test if that's indeed the case, replace above with something like

```
            throw new RuntimeException("can't handle null in result[1]");
```

then re-run Findbugs and see if the warning disappears.